# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when trying to edit

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have simple form in which a user can update data eg Tags

Here is edit blade.php for tags

```xml
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{ __('Tags') }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{dd($tags)}}
            <select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">
                @foreach ($tags as $tag)
                    @foreach ($pages->tags as $pageTag)
                        <option value="{{ $tag->id }}" @if ($pageTag->tag->id === $tag->id) selected="selected" @endif>{{$tag->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when I do `{{dd($tags)}}` I get the following

```
Collection {#299 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => PageListTag {#295 ▼
            #connection: "mysql"
            #table: "page_list_tags"
            #primaryKey: "id"
            #keyType: "int"
            +incrementing: true
            #with: []
            #withCount: []
            #perPage: 15
            +exists: true
            +wasRecentlyCreated: false
            #attributes: array:2 [▼
                "id" => 1
                "name" => "test1"
            ]
            #original: array:2 [▶]
            #changes: []
            #casts: []
            #dates: []
            #dateFormat: null
            #appends: []
            #dispatchesEvents: []
            #observables: []
            #relations: []
            #touches: []
            +timestamps: true
            #hidden: []
            #visible: []
            #fillable: []
            #guarded: array:1 [▼
                0 => "*"
            ]
        }
        1 => PageListTag {#287 ▼
            #connection: "mysql"
            #table: "page_list_tags"
            #primaryKey: "id"
            #keyType: "int"
            +incrementing: true
            #with: []
            #withCount: []
            #perPage: 15
            +exists: true
            +wasRecentlyCreated: false
            #attributes: array:2 [▼
                "id" => 2
                "name" => "test2"
            ]
            #original: array:2 [▶]
            #changes: []
            #casts: []
            #dates: []
            #dateFormat: null
            #appends: []
            #dispatchesEvents: []
            #observables: []
            #relations: []
            #touches: []
            +timestamps: true
            #hidden: []
            #visible: []
            #fillable: []
            #guarded: array:1 [▶]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now when I click edit I get the following error

What am I doing wrong with codes?

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\custom-xammp\htdocs\royalad-dashboard\resources\views\pages\edit.blade.php)

Comment: Are you sure it's throwing an error on the first foreach and not the second? Putting them on separate lines would give you a hint with the error line #.

Comment: what is the content of $pages->tags?

Comment: I checked it return " " it's empty :(

Comment: If `$pages` is a `Collection` (which it likely is due to naming conventions), you can't call `$pages->tags` without first looping `@foreach($pages AS $page)`, then calling `@foreach($page->tags AS $pageTag)`.

Comment: Also, as stated in your previous question `$pageTag->tag->id` isn't going to work... It's `$pageTag->id`, as `$pageTag->tag` is `null`.

Comment: I am looping because I want to display tag for specific page Id, that Is why I am looping, if I just use `   @foreach ($tags as $tag)
                                     
                                   
                                       <option value="{{ $tag->id }}"  selected="selected">{{$tag->name}}</option>
                                    
                                    @endforeach` no errors but displays all tags inside input instead of the one related to the page edited